# APNs not being delivered to one of test devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

What could lead to APNs not being delivered to one of two test devices. Here is what I have checked:

- Added the device using UDID.
- Made sure the device was selected in the provisional profile.
- Inspected all the misc issues i.e. made sure device token is current and correct, notifications are on etc...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, delivery of APNs is not guaranteed.